# Angular2: calling a local object function for img src

Tags: javascript, angular, property-binding

I have following template

```
<div id="collage" class="collage">
    <img *ngIf="photos" *ngFor="#photo of photos" src="photo.getUrl()" [width]="photo.width" [height]="photo.height">
</div>
```

The `photos` is coming as input to the template. The function `photo.getUrl()` just returns a string with some image url. The `CollageComponent` looks like:

```
import {Component, OnChanges, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {Photo} from 'interfaces/photo';

@Component({
    selector: 'collage',
    templateUrl: 'templates/collage.html'
})
export class CollageComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() photos: Photo[];

    ngOnChanges(change) {
        if ('photos' in change && change.photos.currentValue) {
            jQuery('#album-collage').collagePlus({
                'fadeSpeed': 2000,
                'targetHeight': 200
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But in `src` the value that (obviously) coming is the string literal `"photo.getUrl()"`. What should be done here so that the image's `src` gets assigned the value returned by the function `getUrl()`.

Comment: `[src]="photo.getUrl()"`

Comment: I tried that but I was getting this error `EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_photo0.getUrl is not a function in [photo.getUrl() in CollageComponent@1:35]`

Comment: No! its `ngFor #photo of photos`. Probably I understand where is the mistake. I think I am creating Photo object by directly assigning json without calling `new Photo` somewhere in the code. I am not sure. If I find I'll update...